# latency based routing for service endpoints in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, envoyproxy, kubernetes-service

we have single kubernetes cluster which has worker nodes in multiple data-centres which are in different geography area.

we have a service endpoint which connect to the application pods which are in different data-centres. lets say application A has 2 pods running in Data-CentresY, 2 pods in Data-CentreZ and 2 pods in Data-CentreX. now when requests lands on a service endpoint it route traffic to all these 6 pods which are in different data-centres.

we want to implement a latency based routing for service endpoints where when requests lands on a workers node it should route traffic to its nearest pods or pod with low network latency.

any suggestion or guidance are much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Kubeadm or On-Prem (if yes which one, GCP/AWS/AZure)? Did you try anything or think about some solution?

Comment: We deployed cluster using kubeadm. We are running workers node simultaneously on AWS and GCP.   i am not able to find any solution as of now.

Answer (score 1):

Use `kube-proxy` with `ipvs` mode and use `sed` - `shortest expected delay`

Refer: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-ipvs